# How to view Elasticserarch AWS cluster settings

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, settings

I'm trying to update elasticsearch cluster settings on AWS, but
i got this error:

```
Message: "Your request: '/_cluster/settings' is not allowed for verb: GET"
```

My command:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cluster/settings
```

Obs: both Get or Put method not work

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{"persistent" : {"indices.fielddata.cache.size" : "30%"}}'
{"Message":"Your request: '/_cluster/settings' payload is not allowed."}
```

Reference:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-update-settings.html

It's a AWS issue?

Comment: Hello. Which version did you try this on? We're on v7.7 and yet getting the same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is an AWS constraint on ElasticSearch prior to version 5.3.

> Prior to Elasticsearch 5.3, the _cluster/settings API on Amazon ES domains supported only the HTTP PUT method, not the GET method.

AWS supports `_cluster/settings` after Elasticsearch 5.3, and other Elasticsearch operations, but not all. You can refer to their doc:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-supported-es-operations.html#es_version_api_notes